# executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate to run task forever

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

I want a task to run forever after an interval of 1 min. TO accomplish that i wrote my task in

```
public void poll() {
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture files=executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {      
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String path="/Desktop/PNL/Test";
            List<String> filesPaths= new ArrayList<String>();
            File folder= new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles= folder.listFiles();
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                filesPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(filesPaths)){
                try{
                    update(filesPaths);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    files.cancel(false);
    //executorService.shutdown();

}
```

But the task executes only once and not after each minute.
I don't understand whats wrong here.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? At a quick glance I think it may be an issue with how you are invoking it.

Comment: What is that line `files.cancel(false);`? If you cancel the scheduled task, then it obviously won't run anymore.

Comment: @Dibesjr edited the code

Comment: @Jesper i gave the false for that so it can't be interrupted

Comment: @shrutirawat the false means that the task is cancelled (i.e. removed from the executor service) without being sent an interrupt (i.e. just wait for it to finish), not that the runnable can *never* be interrupted.

Comment: @shrutirawat I think you got the answer here. Checkout [Future#cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Cancel attempts to cancel the execution of the scheduled task.

Comment: @AndyTurner iut started working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While executing your code, there was a `NullPointerException` caused at `for (File file : listOfFiles) {` which killed the thread.

The following change made it run continuously:

```
if (listOfFiles != null) {
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        filesPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Moreover, `files.cancel(false)` ends the execution. Hence, had to comment this line. Reference of [Future.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean))

Answer (score 2):

Tested the code. As assumed by the others, the outcome is:
Removing the line

```
files.cancel(false);
```

makes it run every minute. Else it runs only once.

Here is my code for test, which works:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PeriodicCall {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new PeriodicCall().poll();
}

public void poll() {
    System.out.println("poll"); // called once
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture<?> files = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {      
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    //files.cancel(false);
    //executorService.shutdown();
}
}
```

My run() function contains only a System.out.println, so you should check your code inside your run() method. If it contains errors it will abort the whole execution.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After playing in a little sandbox for a minute I restructured your code to work like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable files = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Replace with your original code.. this was just a test to make sure it worked
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    };

    // Set this back to minutes, seconds was easier to test
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(files, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: How would it execute once if it wasn't started?

Comment: I don't get start() option for files.

Comment: I updated it with some code that works on my end @shrutirawat

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you are getting an unchecked exception in your Runnable. The following code prints "Running" exactly once:

```
import java.io.*;                                                                                    
import java.util.concurrent.*;                                                                       

public class Foo {                                                                                   
  public static void main(String[] args) {                                                           
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);                   
    ScheduledFuture files=executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {                       
      @Override                                                                                      
      public void run() {                                                                            
        System.out.println("Running");                                                               
        throw new RuntimeException("bar");                                                           
      }                                                                                              
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                                                                      
  }                                                                                                  
}
```

You should put a try/catch block around everything in your `run()` method, and see what you catch.

```
      @Override                                                                                      
      public void run() {
        try {                                                                            
          System.out.println("Running");                                                               
          throw new RuntimeException("bar");                                                           
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          // Do something better here, but for the sake of highlighting the issue:
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```